# Extract string after first '/' using snowflake query

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, regexp-substr, sql-query-store

I have an input table in snowflake with column contains data pattern as follows

> city, state/LOCATION/designation

> city state/LOCATION/designation

> city, state/LOCATION

Want to extract only location and store in another column, can you help me doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use SPLIT_PART, as mentioned in a previous answer, but if you wanted to use regular expressions I would use `REGEXP_SUBSTR`, like this:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(YOUR_FIELD_HERE,'/([^/]+)',1,1,'e')
```

To break it down, briefly, it's looking for a slash and then takes all the non-slash characters that follow it, meaning it ends just before the next slash, or at the end of the string.

The `1,1,'e'` correspond to: starting at the first character of the string, returning the 1st match, and extracting the substring (everything in the parentheses).

Snowflake documentation is [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_substr.html).

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to do this:

A) using the SPLIT_PART function:

```
SELECT SPLIT_PART('city, state/LOCATION/designation', '/', 2);
```

Reference: [SPLIT_PART](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split_part.html#split-part)

B) using the SPLIT_TO_TABLE tabular function:

```
 SELECT t.VALUE
   FROM TABLE(SPLIT_TO_TABLE('city, state/LOCATION/designation', '/')) AS t
  WHERE t.INDEX = 2;
```

Reference: [SPLIT_TO_TABLE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split_to_table.html#split-to-table)

C) using REGEXP expressions:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('city, state/LOCATION/designation', '(.*)/(.*)/(.*)', '\\2');
```

but this one doesn't work if you don't have a third term ('designation'), you need to combine with two calls and check by number of backslashes.

```
SELECT IFF(REGEXP_COUNT('city, state/LOCATION', '/') = 1,
           REGEXP_REPLACE('city, state/LOCATION','(.*)/(.*)','\\2'), 
           REGEXP_REPLACE('city, state/LOCATION','(.*)/(.*)/(.*)','\\2'));
```

Reference: [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_replace.html)